# Javascript loads on page load not after selection is made

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I have a page which the user can upload photos for products, he selects the brand from the brand select box which will populate the product select box with the products belonging to that brand.

This all worked with with coldfusion, but as we added more products it became slower, i have out putted the products on another page using JSON format. If i go to that page - prod-json.cfm?brand_id=115, it will load all the info correctly. The problem is that i need it to display on the photo page, when the user chooses a specific brand, below is the code that i am using to call that page with the products:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document

// The queryToObject function
var queryToObject = function(q) {
var col, i, r, _i, _len, _ref, _ref2, _results;
_results = [];
for (i = 0, _ref = q.ROWCOUNT; 0 <= _ref ? i < _ref : i > _ref; 0 <= _ref ? i++ : i--) {
  r = {};
  _ref2 = q.COLUMNS;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref2.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    col = _ref2[_i];
    r[col.toLowerCase()] = q.DATA[col][i];
  }
  _results.push(r);
}
return _results;
};

// Read the products
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
url: "prod-json.cfm",
data: {'brand_id': $("##brand_id").val()},
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
  var row, sData, _len, _i;
  // Run the data thru queryToObject
  data = queryToObject(data);
  // Convert the object to a string to display it
  sData = JSON.stringify(data);

  // Print all products
  $('##product_id').append('');
  // Loop over the query
  for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    row = data[_i];
    $('.multiple').append('<option value=' + row.product_id + ' class="' + row.brand_id + '">' +   row.product_title + ' - ' + row.make_title + ' ' + row.model_title + '');
 }
 }
 });
 </script>
```

If i refresh the page with a specific brand selected then it will show the products, but if i choose another brand then it loads nothing, please could someone help me sort this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any results from the AJAX call when you select the second brand?  Anything in your browser console?  Are the ## in the JavaScript because this script is being rendered by ColdFusion?

Comment: Yes the ## are because its coldfusion, there is no response when i have selected another brand, it only shows the products if i leave the brand select box selected with something and then reload the page, thats the only time it works.

Comment: Could you post something on JSFiddle?  When you say there is no response, does that mean it's not making the request, or that ColdFusion isn't returning anything.

Comment: if i test it in google chrome it doesnt say anything in the console about the function, it just states something about another plugin i have on the page. Basically what has to happen is that once the user selects the brand, then the brand id has to be passed to prod-json.cfm which then generate the results based on the id that has been selected. On initial page load when brand is not selected and i select something, nothing happens, i hope this is making sense, if i put it online instead of jsfiddle, would that be better?

Comment: It sounds like it's a JavaScript issue, so jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: im sorry for being a pain, how would i post the coldfusion or json on jsfiddle?

Comment: Start by just posting the rendered HTML onto the jsFiddle.  If this is a public CF page, then just change the AJAX URL to point to the server.

Comment: ok please give me a few minutes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8UYm4/

Comment: i hope that is ok, i have just used 2 brands as we have over 100

Comment: this is a working link for the json with a brand added to the url:http://www.cougar-raceparts.com/testing/prod-json.cfm?brand_id=115

Comment: this is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8UYm4/9/

Comment: function loadData() { is giving me a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that you don't have anything listening for the drop down to be changed.

You can fix this a couple of ways.  The easiest is to wrap the whole AJAX call in another function... something like:

```
function loadData() {
     $.ajax({
  type: "POST", .......
}
```

and then change the top of your code to look like:

```
$(function(){

    $('.styled').customSelect();

    $('#brand_id').change(function() {
        loadData();
    });
    loadData(); // this triggers the initial load for the default value.  might not be necessary
});
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for looking over the code, the javascript that i posted in jsfiddle is actually 3 seperate scripts that i had to paste as one, does the above still apply to that?

Comment: I can't directly test it because of cross domain issues, but it shouldn't take you long to test on your environment

Comment: im really sorry to ask you this as im clueless in js, but how exactly would i implement your code to the code i submitted right at the top?

Comment: I have just got it to work, thank you so much, your solution helped me big time, i appreciate it